# How to output child elements separately, not as one space-delimited string?

Tags: xml, powershell

My current code to select some attributes in XML doesn't seem to work:

```bsh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Makro-Test\quandata.xml'
$xml.QUANDATASET.GROUPDATA.GROUP.SAMPLELISTDATA.SAMPLE | foreach {
  $_.id + ":" + $_.name + ":" + $_.COMPOUND.id + ":" + $_.COMPOUND.name +
    ":" + $_.COMPOUND.PEAK.analconc
}
```

It outputs:

```
1:Aminoacids_Routine_2016_05_30_002:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23:Leu Iso Thre Val Lys Met Phen Try His Gly Ala Ser Arg Cys Tyr Pro Glu Glut Asp Aspa Tau Orn Cit:0.0000000000     0.0000000000   0.0000000000  0.0000000000 0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
2:Aminoacids_Routine_2016_05_30_003:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23:Leu Iso Thre Val Lys Met Phen Try His Gly Ala Ser Arg Cys Tyr Pro Glu Glut Asp Aspa Tau Orn Cit:0.0000000000 0.2336617286 0.2147717292 0.2252815136  0.2299108827 0.2395318825  0.0000000000    0.0000000000 0.0000000000  0.2074479299     0.0000000000  0.0000000000
```

But I want the output to look like that:

```
1;Aminoacids_Routine_2016_05_30_002;1;Leu;0.0000000000
2;Aminoacids_Routine_2016_05_30_002;2;Iso;0.0000000000
...
1;Aminoacids_Routine_2016_05_30_003;1;Leu;0.0000000000
2;Aminoacids_Routine_2016_05_30_003;2;Iso;0.2336617286
...
```

The XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QUANDATASET>
  <XMLFILE>
  <DATASET>
  <GROUPDATA>
    <GROUP>
      <METHODDATA/>
      <SAMPLELISTDATA>
        <SAMPLE id="1" groupid="1" name="Routine_2016_05_30_002">
          <COMPOUND id="1" sampleid="1" groupid="1" name="Leu">
            <PEAK foundscan="0" analconc="0.023423456">
              <ISPEAK/>
            </PEAK>
          </COMPOUND>
          <COMPOUND id="2" sampleid="1" groupid="1" name="Iso">
             <PEAK foundscan="0" analconc="0.123456789">
               <ISPEAK/>
             </PEAK>
          </COMPOUND>
          <COMPOUND id="3" sampleid="1" groupid="1" name="Thre">
          ...
          ...
          ...
        <SAMPLE id="2" groupid="1" name="Routine_2016_05_30_003">
          <COMPOUND id="1" sampleid="2" groupid="1" name="Leu">
          ...
          ...
          ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using [XPath selectors](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) but native PowerShell object property access.

PowerShell 3.0 and newer automatically produces an array of the specified property values when used on an array as a whole.

In case of XML, each repeated element like `COMPOUND` returns an array when accessed by name (that is without index), so the aforementioned behavior applies to `$_.COMPOUND.id`: this is an array! And it's automatically type-coerced into a string by joining the elements with a space in your code.

**Solution 1:** enumerate the child elements manually:

```
$delim = ':'
foreach ($sample in $xml.QUANDATASET.GROUPDATA.GROUP.SAMPLELISTDATA.SAMPLE) {
    foreach ($compound in $sample.COMPOUND) {
        $sample.id, $sample.name,
        $compound.id, $compound.name, [double]$compound.PEAK.analconc -join $delim
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** actually use XPath to select all child elements and access `SAMPLE` as `parentNode`:

```
$delim = ':'
foreach ($compound in $xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND')) {
    $sample = $compound.ParentNode
    $sample.id, $sample.name,
    $compound.id, $compound.name, [double]$compound.PEAK.analconc -join $delim
}
```

Instead of pipelining I'm using `foreach` statement to have a nicely named iterator variable.

Comment: Thanks for this really useful answer and explanation! This is exactly what I was looking for and I have additionally learned something. Thank you

Comment: When array type-coerced into a string, then elements are joined not by space, but by `$OFS`: `$OFS='not_space';[string](1..3)`.

Comment: Good to know. So to be precise: unless you change the default value of $OFS, which is $null, the elements are joined by the space character.

Answer (score 2):

Like [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40152056/1630171) I'd use `SelectNodes()` with an [XPath](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx), but I'd process the output as [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) instead:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND') |
  Select-Object @{n='SampleID';e={[int]$_.ParentNode.id}},
                @{n='SampleName';e={$_.ParentNode.name}},
                @{n='CompoundID';e={[int]$_.id}},
                @{n='CompoundName';e={$_.name}},
                @{n='analconc';e={[double]$_.PEAK.analconc}}
```

That will give you objects to work with instead of a string. If you need the data written to a file you can export it via [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx):

```
... | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed supplement. 
The option of exporting as CSV, I will be able to use best.

Comment: Please see my EDIT in the posted question, regarding processing several xml files to a csv...

Comment: @Benhur262 Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.