# How to loop through XML files and create a CSV file?

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I've got a good working PowerShell script (thanks to Ansgar Wiechers) for an XML file, that exports me the desired fields to a CSV file:

```bsh
$goal = '\\LC\ARCHIV\INPUT_' + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddss) + '.xml'
[xml]$xml = Get-Content '\\mcsonlines-impexp\Onlines\LCMS\IMPORT\*.xml'
$xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND') |
  Select-Object @{n='SampleID';e={[int]$_.ParentNode.id}},
                @{n='SampleName';e={"B" + $_.ParentNode.name}},
                @{n='CompoundID';e={[int]$_.id}},
                @{n='CompoundName';e={$_.name}},
                @{n='analconc';e={[double]$_.PEAK.analconc}} |
  Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'

Move-Item -Path \\LC\IMPORT\*.xml -destination $goal
```

The XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QUANDATASET>
  <XMLFILE>
  <DATASET>
  <GROUPDATA>
    <GROUP>
      <METHODDATA/>
      <SAMPLELISTDATA>
        <SAMPLE id="1" groupid="1" name="Routine_2016_05_30_002">
          <COMPOUND id="1" sampleid="1" groupid="1" name="Leu">
            <PEAK foundscan="0" analconc="0.023423456">
              <ISPEAK/>
            </PEAK>
          </COMPOUND>
          <COMPOUND id="2" sampleid="1" groupid="1" name="Iso">
             <PEAK foundscan="0" analconc="0.123456789">
               <ISPEAK/>
             </PEAK>
          </COMPOUND>
          <COMPOUND id="3" sampleid="1" groupid="1" name="Thre">
          ...
          ...
          ...
        <SAMPLE id="2" groupid="1" name="Routine_2016_05_30_003">
          <COMPOUND id="1" sampleid="2" groupid="1" name="Leu">
          ...
          ...
          ...
```

The CSV Export looks like:

```
SampleID   SampleName  CompoundID  CompoundName    analconc
...
6   Routine_2016_11_11_006  1   Leu 60,30064828
6   Routine_2016_11_11_006  2   Iso 60,38823887
6   Routine_2016_11_11_006  3   Thre 74,00187964
...
```

Now to my question - is it possible to process multiple XML files at once with the script to a CSV file? With my change makes the script unfortunately nothing at all.

First try:

```bsh
$file = Get-ChildItem '\\LC\IMPORT\*.xml' -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
  [xml]$xml = (Get-Content $file)
  $xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND') |
    Select-Object @{n='SampleID';e={[int]$_.ParentNode.id}},
                  @{n='SampleName';e={"B" + $_.ParentNode.name}},
                  @{n='CompoundID';e={[int]$_.id}},
                  @{n='CompoundName';e={$_.name}},
                  @{n='analconc';e={[double]$_.PEAK.analconc}} |
    Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
}
```

This did not work at all.

Second try:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem '\\LC\IMPORT\' *.xml -Recurse | % {
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
  #$goal = '\\LC\ARCHIV\INPUT_' + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddss) + '.xml'

  $xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND') |
    Select-Object @{n='SampleID';e={[int]$_.ParentNode.id}},
                  @{n='SampleName';e={"B" + $_.ParentNode.name}},
                  @{n='CompoundID';e={[int]$_.id}},
                  @{n='CompoundName';e={$_.name}},
                  @{n='analconc';e={[double]$_.PEAK.analconc}} |
    Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
}
```

With this attempt only one XML file is exported to a CSV file.

Here is the link to my first post:

[How to output child elements separately, not as one space-delimited string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151076/how-to-output-child-elements-separately-not-as-one-space-delimited-string)

Comment: You are always overwriting the csv file, use: `[..]Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';' -Append` instead

Comment: @whatever should make that an answer, not a comment. It's the simplest fix for you.

Comment: Thanky you @whatever, yes thats right - it works now with  [..] -Append included!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician will do. What's the propere ettiquette here, do I just delete my original comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach didn't do anything because you collect the list of XML files in a variable `$file`, but then iterate over a variable `$files` (note the trailing "s"), which is empty.

Your second approach overwrites the output file with each iteration, because you use `Export-Csv` *inside* the loop without the parameter `-Append`.

Either put the `Export-Csv` statement *after* the loop:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\LC\IMPORT\*.xml' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName

  $xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND') |
    Select-Object @{n='SampleID';e={[int]$_.ParentNode.id}},
                  @{n='SampleName';e={"B" + $_.ParentNode.name}},
                  @{n='CompoundID';e={[int]$_.id}},
                  @{n='CompoundName';e={$_.name}},
                  @{n='analconc';e={[double]$_.PEAK.analconc}}
} | Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
```

or call `Export-Csv` with the parameter `-Append` *inside* the loop, so that each iteration appends to the CSV:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\LC\IMPORT\*.xml' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName

  $xml.SelectNodes('//COMPOUND') |
    Select-Object @{n='SampleID';e={[int]$_.ParentNode.id}},
                  @{n='SampleName';e={"B" + $_.ParentNode.name}},
                  @{n='CompoundID';e={[int]$_.id}},
                  @{n='CompoundName';e={$_.name}},
                  @{n='analconc';e={[double]$_.PEAK.analconc}} |
    Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -Append -NoType -Delimiter ';'
}
```

The first approach is preferable, though, because it avoids repeatedly opening and closing the output file, so it has better performance. Also, the parameter `-Append` isn't available prior to PowerShell v3, so the second approach requires at least that PowerShell version and will not work on PowerShell v2 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You are always overwriting the csv file, use:

```
[..]Export-Csv '\\LC\IMPORT\quandata.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';' -Append
```

instead. `-Append` will cause powershell to add the new content.